# Try to use Fabian Schmenglers Site Audit tool but getting an error

Tags: installation

I try to use this tool

https://github.com/schmengler/magento-audit

But I am getting this error

```
wget: option requires an argument -- 'O'

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you refer to the installation instruction. A GitHub issue would have been a more appropriate place to discuss this. However, you may try

```
wget https://github.com/schmengler/magento-audit/tarball/master -O - | tar -xz
```

instead. Alternatively, just clone the repository or [download the release](https://github.com/schmengler/magento-audit/releases).

Comment: Indeed the `-` was missing. Thanks for pointing it out, I updated the README accordingly.

Comment: @fschmengler is this audit possible with Magento Enterprise 1.7.1? 
I´m getting this error

Generate reports...
Could not open input file: downloader/mage.php



  [Exception]
  Notice: Undefined variable: pathToVanillaCore  in /../../.n98-magerun/modules/mpmd/src/Mpmd/Magento/CodePoolOverrides
  Command.php on line 58

Comment: The tool's [README](https://github.com/schmengler/magento-audit/blob/v0.1.1/README.md#usage) states that a clean Magento gets downloaded from the Magento website. As you may know, EEs are not available for public download. So the answer for the current version must be **no**. Apart from that: Why not open a GitHub issue?

Comment: The script that downloads Magento is written for CE, where the URL is publicly accessible. For EE you should download the unmodified core manually and copy the magento directory to ~/magento-1.7.0.0/magento. Replace 1.7.0.0 with the exact version that the script shows as "Downloading Magento XXX"